# Shifting with uint64_t not working as expected

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, c99

For part of a larger task, I was asked to implement a function that flips an arbitrary bit in an integer. The catch is that the "integer" could be any of the default integer types in c, from int8_t to uint64_t, and I don't know which one it will be. (In fact, my code has been tested on all of these types)

This was my attempt at the problem:

```
//NOTE: g_int is the generic integer, it's typedef'd in a .h file
g_int flip_bit(g_int b, uint8_t i){
    //Code that makes sure i is a valid amount to shift by, there's a macro
    //that defines the upper bound of i in a .h file.
    g_int flipped = b ^ (1<<i);
    return flipped;
}
```

This code xors the `i`th bit in `b` with 1, and the other bits in `b` with 0. This should flip the `i`th bit while leaving the rest unchanged. Satisfied with this, I tested my code on all of these different integer sizes, and then turned it in. However, I must not have tested enough, as my code failed on both int64_t and uint64_t.

What did I do wrong for int64_t and uint64_t, and is there something I can do to make my method work without changing it entirely?

Comment: Sure, I can edit it. generic wasn't the actual name of the type in the assignment, I just changed it quickly so as to indicate its meaning. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: How is `g_int` defined in the  .h file?  It is always the same throughout a build?  It may impact how `flip_bit()` can be used.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I meant that when my code is tested, there are a bunch of different .h files that test it with the same name, tested one at a time, with all of these different integer types for each one. My method has to work for each of them.

Comment: 1) The trick is how, in a  large project, how would one .c file use `flip_bit()` with one type and another .c file use it with another?  There are ways to do this.  Yet if the goal is only _one_ type for the entire build, no problem with what you have. 2) I see no advantage of using `uint8_t i` vs. `unsigned i`, yet some minor disadvantages - although neither is central to the `1 <<` issue.

Comment: There's a .h file that declares this function as well. Actually, the typedef that defines `g_int` is the same one that holds this `flip_bit()` method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This problem is caused by the type of 1, which is int (which has 32 bits on a reasonable machine). This means that performing the shift `(1<<i)` for values of  i greater than or equal to 32 will result in undefined behavior.

This can be fixed simply by casting 1 to type `g_int` before performing the shift:

```
g_int flip_bit(g_int b, uint8_t i){
    g_int flipped = b ^ (((g_int)1)<<i);
    return flipped;
}
```

Comment: The only correction is that shifting beyond the width of the integer is *undefined behavior* (not zero). http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.7p4

Comment: *undefined behaviour* is different to "undefined value". Anything could happen at all, not just an unexpected value.

Comment: My bad, I just changed it quickly. I'll fix it.